# Merge anonymous lead with known lead with Marketo REST API

Tags: rest, merge, anonymous, marketo, known-types

I have anonymous leads in Marketo and I need to merge them with known leads through the REST API.

I am trying the code below

```
public function postData() {
    $url = $this->host . "/rest/v1/leads/" . $this->id ."/merge.json?access_token=" . $this->getToken() . "&leadIds=" . $this::csvString($this->leadIds);

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/json",
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
}
```

It is responding with `{"requestId":"1af7#fgfdhgfdgfgdfg","success":false,"errors":[{"code":"1004","message":"Lead '231325' not found"}]}` but I can see the lead with the id *231325* in Marketo.

How can I merge the anonymous lead with the known lead with REST?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that, or not in a straightforward way.
The description of the [Merge functionality](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/lead-database/leads/#merge) in the Docs does not states it as clearly as the [Merge Endpoint reference](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Leads/mergeLeadsUsingPOST), but it "*merges **two or more known** lead records into a single lead record*". So even if you see the MarketoIds of these *visitors* in the system, the API won't find them in the Leads table.

However, depending on your exact goal and setup, you might solve your issue by using the [Associate Web Activity](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/lead-database/leads/#associate_web_activity) functionality, as it "*associates a **known** Marketo lead record to a **munchkin cookie** and its associated web activity history*". The [Associate Endpoint](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Leads/associateLeadUsingPOST) expects the value of the `_mkto_trk` cookie of a visitor (sample format: `id:287-GTJ-838%26token:_mch-marketo.com-1396310362214-46169`).

Having said that, your `curl` would look something like this:

```
$url = $host . '/rest/v1/leads/' . $leadId . '/associate.json?cookie=' . $cookie . '&access_token=' . $token;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

You can obtain the value of the cookie with `$_COOKIE['_mkto_trk']`.